# How do you use java stream api to convert list of objects into a nested map based on information stored inside object?

Tags: java, date, java-stream

I have a list of objects `List<SingleDay>` where `SingleDay` is

```
class SingleDay{ 
      private Date date;
      private String County;

   // otherstuff
}
```

Im looking to convert this list into a `Map<Date, Map<String, SingleDay>>`. That is, I want a map from Date to a map of Counties back to the original object.

For example:
`02/12/2020 : { "Rockbridge": {SingleDayObject}}`

I have not been able to get anything to work and everything I found online if from a list of objects to a map, not a list of objects to a nested map.

Basically, I want to be able to quickly query the object that corresponds to the date and county.

Thanks!

Comment: You can think you storing the data in Map<String,SingleDay> where string can be 'date:country' and value is singleDay object

Comment: Is there a chance of having `SingleDay` object with duplicate `date` and `country`?

Comment: @Deadpool no, but I would like to know how to handle that if it were to happen accidentally. Im reading from a csv so it would be possible I suppose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
Map<LocalDate, Map<String, SingleDay>> result = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(SingleDay::getDate, v -> Map.of(v.getCounty(), v)));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class SingleDay {
    private LocalDate date;
    private String County;

    public SingleDay(LocalDate date, String county) {
        this.date = date;
        County = county;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getCounty() {
        return County;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SingleDay [date=" + date + ", County=" + County + "]";
    }
    // otherstuff
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SingleDay> list = List.of(new SingleDay(LocalDate.now(), "X"),
                new SingleDay(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), "Y"), new SingleDay(LocalDate.now().plusDays(2), "Z"));

        Map<LocalDate, Map<String, SingleDay>> result = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(SingleDay::getDate, v -> Map.of(v.getCounty(), v)));

        // Display
        result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key: " + k + ", Value: " + v));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Key: 2020-05-27, Value: {Z=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County=Z]}
Key: 2020-05-26, Value: {Y=SingleDay [date=2020-05-26, County=Y]}
Key: 2020-05-25, Value: {X=SingleDay [date=2020-05-25, County=X]}
```

**Note:** I've used `LocalDate` instead of outdated `java.util.Date`. I highly recommend you use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) API instead of broken `java.util.Date`. Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to learn more about it.

Comment: Nice answer +1. I do get the following warning `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Date,Object> to Map<Date,Map<String,SingleDay>>`

Comment: good recommendation on using `LocalDate` rather than `Date` although I am not quite sure on your solution overall. shouldn't the expected result be something along the lines of `list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(SingleDay::getDate, v -> Map.of(v.getCounty(), v)));` ? or I'm I missing something from OPs criteria? with your current approach every outer map mapping will have the same value for the inner map.

Comment: Thanks, @OusmaneD. for the feedback. I was not sure about it when I wrote the solution but after going your comment, I think it makes sense. I've incorporated your suggestion. I'll wait for OP's comment if he was expecting this or the original solution.

Comment: Question is tagged with java-8.  `Map.of` is feature of java9+

Comment: @Code_Mode actually question wasn't initially tagged with java-8.  hence me suggesting `Map.of`.

Comment: @JacFrall - We will need some more code to understand why you are getting the compilation error. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62005476/edit) your question and post some code which uses the solution.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I just added the function that has the warning. let me know if this is not sufficient

Comment: @JacFrall - Are you sure you want to use `Date` instead of `LocalDate`? So far, I haven't found any problem in your code. Let me check more closely. By the way, I suggest you try with my updated answer and let me know if the error persists. Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I found the bug, and also your new answer works too. Thanks! I will accept your answer shortly. BTW, what is the difference, what change did you make to the original answer.

Comment: @JacFrall - Perfect! Wish you success!

Comment: The original answer was collecting the whole list into `Map` against the `date` key and the updated answer (thanks to @OusmaneD. for his timely suggestion) is putting the value of the entry against the key.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what we would have to change to if there were duplicate dates and we want: `Key: 2020-05-27, Value: {Z=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County=Z], Y=SingleDay [date=2020-05-26, County=Y], X=SingleDay [date=2020-05-25, County=X]}`

Comment: @JacFrall - A `Map` can not have duplicate keys. Also, the structure of the output that you have posted in the comment matches with the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62005777/1).

Comment: I apologize, this is what I meant to type. Note that they all have the same date now. It simply aggregates by date and creates a map from county to original object. Of course, this is just one key, there would be many keys since there are many dates, though there are duplicates. `Key: 2020-05-27, Value: {Z=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County=Z], Y=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County=Y], X=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County=X]}`

Comment: Its up! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027187/how-to-aggregate-based-on-certain-value-and-create-nested-map-given-a-list-of-ob

Comment: Thanks for posting a new question to avoid polluting this Q/A. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score -1):

A slightly more readable data structure would be making a `Map<SingleDay, SingleDay>`. Might seem redundant but that will allow you to easily find your objects.

```
Map<SingleDay, SingleDay> myMap = new HashMap();
list.forEach(day -> myMap.put(day, day));
```

Then to get one you can just do

```
SingleDay day = mMap.get(myDay);
```

Very important to not forget to override the `equals()` method of `SingleDay`, based on what you consider as equal.

Comment: But then, given a date I wouldnt be able to find the corresponding SingleDays. I would already need it, right