# How to aggregate based on certain value and create nested map given a list of objects?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List<SingleDay>` where `SingleDay` is:

```
class SingleDay{ 
      private Date date;
      private String County;

   // otherstuff
}
```

I would like to convert this into a `Map<LocalDate, Map<String,SingleDay>>` by the following transformation:

```
Key: 2020-05-27, Value: {'County1'=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County='County1'],
                         'County2'=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County='County2'], 
                         'County3'=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County='County3']
                        }
Key: 2020-05-28, Value: {'County4'=SingleDay [date=2020-05-28, County='County4'],
                         'County5'=SingleDay [date=2020-05-28, County='County5'], 
                         'County3'=SingleDay [date=2020-05-28, County='County3']
                        }
```

Note, this is a question that arose from my previous question : [How do you use java stream api to convert list of objects into a nested map based on information stored inside object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62005476/how-do-you-use-java-stream-api-to-convert-list-of-objects-into-a-nested-map-base?noredirect=1#62005777)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
Map<LocalDate, Map<String, SingleDay>> result = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SingleDay::getDate, Collectors.toMap(SingleDay::getCounty, e -> e)));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class SingleDay {
    private LocalDate date;
    private String County;

    public SingleDay(LocalDate date, String county) {
        this.date = date;
        County = county;
    }
    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getCounty() {
        return County;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SingleDay [date=" + date + ", County=" + County + "]";
    }
    // otherstuff
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SingleDay> list = List.of(
                new SingleDay(LocalDate.now(), "X"), 
                new SingleDay(LocalDate.now(), "Y"),
                new SingleDay(LocalDate.now(), "Z"), 
                new SingleDay(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), "A"),
                new SingleDay(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), "B"), 
                new SingleDay(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), "C"));

        Map<LocalDate, Map<String, SingleDay>> result = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SingleDay::getDate, Collectors.toMap(SingleDay::getCounty, e -> e)));

        // Display
        result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key: " + k + ", Value: " + v));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Key: 2020-05-27, Value: {A=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County=A], B=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County=B], C=SingleDay [date=2020-05-27, County=C]}
Key: 2020-05-26, Value: {X=SingleDay [date=2020-05-26, County=X], Y=SingleDay [date=2020-05-26, County=Y], Z=SingleDay [date=2020-05-26, County=Z]}
```

Comment: +1, you may also be interested in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027470/how-to-best-store-data-from-csv-in-java-class-a-single-list-of-row-objects-or, which is what inspired the question yesterday

Comment: @JacFrall - You are most welcome. Wish you success!

Comment: I'll check that later as I've to rush to attend something else right now. I hope, you will have some answers by then.

Comment: Super fast answer !

Comment: Thanks, @Eklavya for the feedback. It's just because I already knew the context (check the link posted in the question). I've yet to learn a lot of things about the `Stream` API.

Comment: @JacFrall - I'm back. I just checked [the question whose link you have posted above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027470). The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62028171/10819573) looks good to me.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I agree, thanks for taking a look! You are a nice person :)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash  Actually I started writing the answer, then your answer came. I also try to learn and answer Stream API question.